# Перекрытие буфера ввода в C

Tags: c, процесс, ipc, обработка-сигналов

возникла проблема при программировании на языке C.
Главный процесс ожидает ввода строки, но при нажатии control+c должна происходить обработка сигнала так, чтобы пользователь ввел строку, которая будем менять режим работы программы. При вводе команды в обработчик сигналов и дальнейшем вводе строки, которую я хочу обработать, первые N символов строки, где N - длина строки команды, введенной для работы обработчика сигналов, просто обрезаются. Как очистить буфер ввода или же сделать так, чтобы не было перекрытия двух вводов, fflush(stdin) не работает корректно на не-macos системах. Код прилагается. https://pastebin.com/Timw80tG.
Пример ввода:
Ввожу ctrl+c, затем swapreg. После этого вводится слово abcdefgHJK, обрабатывается только HJK.

Comment: Не надо делать такое в обработчике. Выставите в обработчике флаг, а затем в основном цикле отреагируйте на него

Comment: Задание как раз стоит сделать такую вещь в обработчике. Даже если бы можно было по-другому, то все равно возникает вопрос, почему происходит такое перекрытие в стандартном вводе, как это можно качественно фиксить, если fflush(stdin) имеет неопределенный характер на ubuntu. Простенький пример некорректной работы есть в этом коде - https://pastebin.com/5EPvXEaN.

Comment: Почитайте [man 7 signal-safety](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), если такой постановки задачи, как вам дали, нельзя избежать, то  вам придется либо программировать небуферизованный ввод (на  уровне read()), либо писать свою (signal safety) версию stdio